# Flutter camera error LateInitializationError: Field 'cameraController' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, camera

I'm trying to write a code to use the camera with Flutter, but even by following the steps seen online it cannot initialize `cameraController`.

Here is my code :

```dart
class CameraPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CameraPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CameraPage> createState() => _CameraPageState();
}

class _CameraPageState extends State<CameraPage> {

  late List<CameraDescription> cameras;
  late CameraController cameraController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    startCamera();
    super.initState();
  }

  void startCamera() async {
    cameras = await availableCameras();

    cameraController = CameraController(
        cameras[0],
        ResolutionPreset.high
    );

    print(" Camera controller : $cameraController");

    cameraController.initialize().then((value) {
      if(!mounted) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {}); //To refresh widget

    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }



  @override
  void dispose() {
    cameraController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    if(cameraController.value.isInitialized) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            CameraPreview(cameraController),
          ],
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return SizedBox();
    }
  }
}
```

The `print(" Camera controller : $cameraController");` is working fine and returns me a camera controller, so it might be initialized at some point ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest using FutureBuilder to handle future method.

```dart
class _CameraPageState extends State<CameraPage> {
  late List<CameraDescription> cameras;
  late CameraController cameraController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> startCamera() async {
    cameras = await availableCameras();
    cameraController = CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.high);
  }

  late final cameraInit = Future.wait([
    startCamera(),
    cameraController.initialize(),
  ]);
  @override
  void dispose() {
    cameraController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          FutureBuilder(
            future: cameraInit,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                return CameraPreview(cameraController);
              } else {
                return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also check this [cookbook](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/plugins/picture-using-camera).

Comment: At first, your answer wasn't working at all, then I tried to google all the errors appearing, and then I found a compiler problem. I was compiling with android SDK 33 but turns out there is a bug with opening the camera.
So, if anyone is having my situation don't use Target SDK 33 but 32 maximum. Otherwise, your camera won't open and your app will eventually crash.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that in the first build your camera controller is not initialized yet, because initialization is in an async method. You can use a Boolean flag to track is initialized, before accessing the late property.

```
bool _cameraInitialized = false;

void startCamera() async {
    cameras = await availableCameras();

    cameraController = CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.high);

    print(" Camera controller : $cameraController");

    cameraController.initialize().then((value) {
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {
        _cameraInitialized = true; // updating the flag after camera is initialized
      }); //To refresh widget
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_cameraInitialized && cameraController.value.isInitialized) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            CameraPreview(cameraController),
          ],
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return SizedBox();
    }
  }
```